# Flutter User ColorFiltered to dark image with matrix

Tags: flutter

I want in flutter to user ColorFiltered, so i can make jpg image dark here is my code but i didn't get the right result, i don't understand matrix and how to change color this code was from internet, please any idea will be welcome.

```
ColorFiltered(
              child: ColorFiltered(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'myimage.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(
                  [
                    //R  G   B    A  Const
                    -1, 0, 0, 0, 190, //
                    0, -1, 0, 0, 255, //
                    0, 0, -1, 0, 255, //
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white,
                BlendMode.darken,
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the result based on my search and a little refactoring :

```
static ColorFilter brightnessAdjust(double value) {
    if (value >= 0.0) {
      value = value * 255;
    } else {
      value = value * 100;
    }
    List<double> matrix;
    if (value == 0) {
      matrix = identityMatrix;
    } else {
      matrix = [
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        value,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        value,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        value,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0
      ];
    }

    return ColorFilter.matrix(matrix);
  }
```

positive value to lighten and negative value to darken (-1 to 1), zero no change anything

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to make your image darker the better solution is probably just putting a transparent black `Container` over your image with a `Stack` widget:

```dart
Stack(children: <Widget>[
  Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
  Positioned.fill(
    child: Opacity(
      opacity: 0.5,
      child: Container(
        color: const Color(0xFF000000),
      ),
    ),
  ),
]),
```

If you really want to use `ColorFiltered` let me know but you can do something like this:

```dart
ColorFiltered(
  child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
  colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
    Color(0xFF3D3D3D),
    BlendMode.darken,
  ),
),
```

Keep in mind that `ColorFiltered` will not just add a new grey layer over the image. It transforms every pixel of the image separately.
As per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ColorFiltered-class.html):

> This widget applies a function independently to each pixel of child's content, according to the ColorFilter specified.